# When will the Woot! Enthusiast sponsorship end?

Tags: discussion, activity-badges

It's getting a bit old. And it creates a ton of questions like "what's the enthusiast badge" and "why is the woot badge also called enthusiast".

Comment: The day before people start asking where their woot! badges went and what's the deal with this Enthusiast?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

<s>December 31 2009</s>

We have been officially dewooted.

I love the woot! guys (they are very cool, and we plan to have them on a future podcast) but *man* was I sick of that particular promotion.