# Can I find out my Stack Overflow login history? 

Tags: support, login, revisions-list, activity-badges

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Consecutive Day Count in profile](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/865/consecutive-day-count-in-profile)

How can I know my log in history for Stack Overflow?

I want to check for how many consecutive days I have logged into Stack Overflow...

This will be helpful to get [Woot badge](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/24444/when-will-the-woot-enthusiast-sponsorship-end).

Comment: BTW, "woot" no longer exists; you'll have to settle for Enthusiast: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/24444/when-will-the-woot-enthusiast-sponsorship-end